# wordpress blog connects with php website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress blog and php website.
I'd like to put the information about new articles on wordpress blog to the php website.
I did something.  I have titles of articles.
But I need  featured images and descriptions as well.

Here is code which I put on my php website.

```
<?php 
      // connection with wordpress
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost", "...", "....");
mysql_select_db ("...", $db);

$result_redaktor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' ORDER by post_date DESC LIMIT 10", $db);

if (!$result_redaktor)
{

exit (mysql_error()); 
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result_redaktor) > 0)

{
$myrow_redaktor = mysql_fetch_array($result_redaktor);

do
{
printf ("<div class='main'>
    <a href='http://redaktor.11klassniki.ru/%s'>%s</a></div>"
    , $myrow_redaktor["guid"], $myrow_redaktor["post_title"]);
}

while ($myrow_redaktor = mysql_fetch_array($result_redaktor));
}
else 
{
echo "<p>no data.</p>";
exit ();
}
include ("blocks/bd.php");
?>
```

I don't know how to get featured image and text (lead, which goes before tag more).

**P.S My site and my blog are in the same hosting.**

This code allows to see titles. It works. But I need to add pictures to titles.

How can I customize next code

```
  $thumbnails = get_posts('numberposts=10');
  foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
      echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail');
      echo '</a>';
    }
  }

  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use wordpress RSS, read this article for more info:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-is-rss-how-to-use-rss-in-wordpress/

Or, if your site and your blog are in the same hosting, you should include wp-load.php file in your php site and use all the function wordpress to show posts.

One example from http://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-recent-posts:

```
// Include the wp-load'er
include('wp-load.php');

// Get the last 10 posts
// Returns posts as arrays instead of get_posts' objects
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 10
));

// Do something with them
echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
    echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Enjoy your code!